# Symfony: How can I create user-templates from filled out forms

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony1

In my Symfony project I'm trying to provide a "save as template"-button for an embedded Form. The embedded form contains dynamic embedded forms itself.

Example:

[image]

The user should be able to save the template without saving the whole form. So i'm going to use AJAX to achieve this (as I already did, for the dynamic add-behavior).

The actual problem is that Symfony names the form in dependence on the parent form, e.g.

```
<input name="Project[Workflow][1][name]" />
```

But the template isn't related to "Project" at all. On the other hand, this naming format is required later, when saving the whole form.

Sending the whole form to the server might be a solution, but I think it's a bad practice / overkill / waste of bandwidth.

Is there a common way how to do this?
If not, do you have a basic approach in mind?

Regards,
Uli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

symfony `sfForms` take 2 `array`s on the `bind` method, you don't really need to take them from the request.

since you have several `WorkflowForm`s there is a loop involved!

```
    $formData = $request->getParameter('Project'); // you could do Project['Workflow'] except for symfony 1.4

    foreach ($formData['Workflow'] as $embeddedData)
    {
      $formFiles = $request->getFiles('Project');
      $embeddedFiles = $formFiles['Workflow'];
      $form = new WorkflowForm();
      $form->bind($embeddedData, $embeddedFiles);

      if ($form->isValid())
      {
        // do your thing
        // ...
        $form->save();
      }
    }
```

then you process each form as you would usually do on `// do your thing`

Comment: that means I have to use JavaScript for manually collecting the form-fields and building my request-param as suggested (Project['Workflow']), right?

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't get that. The problem is that I need a naming format like "WorkflowTemplate['Workflow']". So maybe I can use JavaScript (see comment above) for the naming problem and then I need a way to pass the form data to a new instance of WorkflowTemplate (maybe you know an easy one), then workflowTemplate->save();

Comment: Okay I had a wrong understanding of what a form does. Of course I need one for validation. But are you sure that I don't have to loop through $projectParam["Workflow"]?